# Is an open interval, a co-zero set? What about the interval (0, 1]. Is it a co-zero set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have the following information about co-zero set.
A subset U of a space X is said to be co-zero subset if there exists a continuous real valued function g on X such that U={xϵ X:g(x)≠0}. Every co-zero set is open. But converse is not true.

Comment: But the converse is true for metric spaces, isn't it? So an open subset of the real line is a cozero set?

Comment: As you note, every co-zero set is open. So if $(0,1]$ is a co-zero set, then it's open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Considering your *Real Analysis* tag, I assume throughout that the space $X = \mathbb{R}$.)

**To your latter question:** You state that *every co-zero set is open*. Observe that $(0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is *not* open (it is neither open nor closed). So, it cannot be a co-zero set.

**To your former question:** Sure. Consider the open interval $(a, b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$.

Define a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows:

If $x \leq a$, then $f(x) = 0$.

If $x \in (a, b)$, then $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$ -- think of the parabola defined by zeroes at $a$ and $b$.

If $x \geq b$, then $f(x) = 0$.

Then $f$ is a continuous function that is non-zero in $(a,b)$ and zero otherwise, as desired. **QED**.

Comment: For $x\in(a,b)$, $f(x)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$

Comment: @egreg Great; thanks! I put it into factored form just to make it slightly clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Benjamin and Egreg